# Print errors of included files to screen, WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress script which includes other files. However somewhere is a bug but only the errors in the main file (which I call from browser) are being printed. 
The errors that occur in included files don't get printed. The process is just exited, so I have no idea how to fix this bug.

Can I add something like:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

to get all errors to print?

Comment: `print_r(get_included_files());` Shows array with files included in order. Shutdown Version: `register_shutdown_function(function(){print_r(get_included_files());});`

Comment: By the way, you should turn on error loggin from PHP and check the logfiles. `Can I add something like` Has wordpress no documentation? And if `wordpress` uses `ob_cache` take the shutdown function above and add `while(ob_get_level()){ob_flush();}` This ensures that if ob_cache is used, after an fatal error, all not flushed data will be flushed,